# Is there an option to call Jenkinsfile from Jenkins job (like how we specify script path in pipeline)?

Tags: jenkins

If the above is not possible, is there a way to write groovy script to call Jenkinsfiles within Jenkins job

Comment: What is your use case for wanting to run the jenkinsfile from a jenkins job?

Comment: I wanted to use BuildResultTrigger plugin to establish conditional Build Trigger(If JobA success then only schedule JobB for later time). As this is not possible with Pipeline job, I wanted to split the pipeline into 2 separate Jobs. However, the Pipeline is customized with Jenkisfile which also reads parameter file within. I wanted to re-use that Jenkins file with the Jenkins jobs that I am planning to create.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Job B from Job A as a downstream job in pipeline and even pass parameters to it like so:

`build job: 'CloudBees/Folder/To/JobB', propagate: false, wait: false, parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PARAM_NAME', value: "${env.SOMEVALUE}"]]`

I use this to only call Job B from Job A at the end of Job A in a post build success clause.  The success clause only executes if Job A still has a job status of SUCCESS at that point.

```
post {
    success {
        script {
            build job: 'CloudBees/Folder/To/JobB', propagate: false, wait: false, parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'PARAM_NAME', value: "${env.SOMEVALUE}"]]
        }
    }
}
```